# Filtering a range of data using InputBox

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, inputbox

I need to filer a dynamic table (about 200 rows/4 columns). I want to enter the filter criteria, in the form of a range, with an InputBox.

I need a button that throws an InputBox asking the user to "Enter a range of Serial Numbers" (eg "7-9" and "15-25"), then filter table.("Serial  Number" is one the columns of the table.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible yes, and the Macro Recorder will be able to do most of it for you. Start the recorder, select your data, apply an auto-filter to the id column with a custom filter which allows both >= and <= a value.  Then stop the recorder.

You just then need to go into the VBA Editor and modify the macro to take variable input.

Example:

**Macro Output**

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$53").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=5", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=10"
End Sub
```

**Modified Macro**

```
Public Sub Macro1m()
Dim A As String
Dim B() As String
Dim Lv As Integer
Dim Hv As Integer
Dim Sv As Integer

    A = InputBox("Enter Criteria: ( [low]-[high] )") ' take your input from the user

    B = Split(A, "-") ' split the result to get the high and low values

    Lv = CInt(B(0)) ' convert the strings to integers
    Hv = CInt(B(1)) ' 

    If Lv > Hv Then ' ensure that the high value is > than low value, swapping if needed
        Sv = Hv
        Hv = Lv
        Lv = Sv
    End If

    Columns("A:C").Select ' original macro code
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$53").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Lv, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Hv ' macro code modified to use high and low value instead of the constant 5 and 10 entered in the auto-filter configuration

End Sub
```